# Di chi sono «i riguardi» in questa frase da Pirandello?

Tags: meaning, sentences

Nel «Fu Mattia Pascal» da Luigi Pirandello c'è questo passaggio:

> Io e Berto, giovinetti, eravamo qualche volta invitati a pranzo dal Malagna. Era uno spasso sentirgli fare, *coi dovuti riguardi*, una predica alla moglie su la continenza, mentre lui mangiava, divorava con tanta voluttà i cibi più succulenti.
>
> — Non ammetto, — diceva, — che per il momentaneo piacere che prova la gola al passaggio d’un boccone, per esempio, come questo — (e giù il boccone) — si debba poi star male un’intera giornata. Che sugo c’è? Io son certo che me ne sentirei, dopo, profondamente avvilito. Rosina! — (chiamava la serva) — Dammene ancora un po’. Buona, questa salsa majonese!

Chi ebbe i riguardi? Il Malagna o i fratelli Pascal (Berto e Mattia)? Credo che sia Malagna, ma vorrei verificarla… Penso così perché la moglie del Malagna «nasceva bene», e il Malagna stesso no; e il carattere della sua moglie non era bello…

Grazie!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il Malagna, in quanto Berto e Mattia erano ospiti e lo ascoltavano  predicare [continenza](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/continenza/) alla moglie, (cioè moderazione nel soddisfacimento dei bisogni materiali e dei piaceri) mentre si abbuffava a tavola.

L'espressione ***coi dovuti riguardi*** indica che il rimprovero verso la moglie era comunque moderato, non aggressivo o particolarmente offensivo nei suoi confronti in modo da non suscitare una reazione violenta a causa del suo pessimo carattere.

Infatti con il termine ***[riguardo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/riguardo/)*** si intende (Treccani):

> **3. a**. Attenzione, avvertenza premurosa, scrupolo a non arrecare disturbo o noia a qualcuno, a non urtarne la suscettibilità e in
>   genere a non mancare alle norme dell’educazione e del rispetto nei
>   suoi confronti: tratta i genitori con ogni r.; esponigli pure il tuo
>   dissenso usando però gli opportuni, i debiti, i giusti r.; compòrtati
>   con tutti i r. dovuti alla sua età; è un maleducato che non ha r. per
>   nessuno; per riguardo verso di te non ho protestato; dimmi se qualcuno
>   ti ha mancato di riguardo; con sign. lievemente diversi: chiedimi pure
>   ciò di cui hai bisogno senza riguardi, o non aver riguardi, sèrviti
>   ancora del dolce, senza fare complimenti; io le cose gliele dico in
>   faccia, senza tanti r., con franchezza, senza che niente mi trattenga,
>   senza velare le parole. **b.** Considerazione, rispetto, stima: la
>   cortesia del gran Lombardo ... Ch’in te avrà sì benigno r. (Dante);
>   comportamenti villani che rivelano mancanza di r. verso il prossimo. È
>   com. in alcune espressioni come una persona, un signore che merita
>   ogni r., che ha diritto a ogni r.; e nella locuz. agg. di riguardo (o,
>   sottolineando, di molto r., di gran r.), con riferimento a persone che
>   per autorità, per la dignità ricoperta o per altra qualità non debbono
>   essere trattate familiarmente: un personaggio di r.; avremo a pranzo
>   ospiti di gran r. (e analogam.: oggi abbiamo visite di riguardo).
>   Anche riferito a cose: vestito che va tenuto, indossato con r.;
>   vestito di r., che si mette solo nelle grandi occasioni, o, più
>   genericam., di pregio; in filologia e nelle discipline affini, copia
>   di r. (analogam. a copia di presentazione), manoscritto destinato a
>   persona autorevole.

Comment: Grazie. Pensavo che potrebbe essere il sign. 2; i riguardi nel avere uno spasso, cioè nel ascoltare alla conversazione (a non ridere, ecc)…

Comment: Hai ragione, modifico la risposta per completezza